# Are Action and Action<T> completely different?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I want to check `if (obj is Action)` but don't know its parameters?

so I want to execute this code whether the obj is `Action`, `Action<string>`, or
`Action<sting, int, bool>`.. etc.

```
if(obj is Action)
{
   //..
}
```

Comment: If you don´t know thw generic type argument, how are you calling the delegate?

Comment: I would suggest to replace your check with `obj is Delegate`. Then you can dynamically invoke that delegate, because that is what as I understand you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are *related*, but yes they are different. There is no inheritance or interface relationship between them and you cast between them. The only formal relationship is that they both subclass `Delegate`. Beyond that, they are just ... kinda friends that we talk about in the same breath a lot.

```
if(obj is Action)
```

will work for the parameterless version, but not for the versions with parameters, as you'd need to *know in advance* the `T` values; you could check for:

```
if(obj is Action<int>)
```

for example, but not *everything*. You can *cheat* with `dynamic` (there are ways to use `dynamic` to flip between reflection and generics with the DLR picking the correct generic type arguments), but by the time you've done that you might just as well use `.DynamicInvoke(args)`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT :**
To distinguish which `Action` variation you're trying to call you can simply do something like that :

```
const string TYPENAME = "System.Action";
Type objType = obj.GetType();
if(objType.ToString().StartsWith(TYPENAME)) // it is Action
{
    Type[] genericArguments = objType.GetGenericArguments();
    object[] parameters = new object[genericArguments.Length];
    // fill your parameters

    (obj as MulticastDelegate).DynamicInvoke(parameters);
}
```

[Online example](http://rextester.com/BTHR7327)

Comment: won't the first `if` fail if it has generic type parameters?

Comment: @adjan Yes it will, Thought about this after I've posted the answer. Now added some explanation

Comment: What type is a *subclass* of `Action` ? delegates don't normally inherit from each-other... in fact, `Action` is marked as `sealed` (pretty sure all concrete delegates are)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the hint, fixed it now.